# importing custom java packages in sublime text 3

Tags: java, eclipse, import, sublimetext3, importerror

I'm trying to import custom java packages in sublime text 3.
Here is the gist of the directory:

```
OuterDirectory
|________ Chapter02
          |___________Question1
                      |___________ MyClassTryingToImport.java
|________ Helperlib
          |___________ MyClass.java

// MyClassTryigToImport.java
import Helperlib.MyClass; // error: package Helperlib does not exist

//MyClass.java
package Helperlib;
public class MyClass { ... }
```

Please do not say to just use eclipse, but rather offer a solution.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your problem is almost certainly that you're using the `JavaC` build system that ships with Sublime, which is not the right thing to do because it invokes the java compiler with no arguments other than the name of the current file. If you want to use stock Sublime you should install `Ant` and make an ant build file and use the `Ant` build system instead.

Comment: @OdatNurd thanks for the comment. I installed Ant via homebrew, went to tools/build system and chose ANT. Can I have the 'build.xml' file at the root of the directory ? and if yes, I have no idea what to actually put in this file. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

For the most part your question doesn't really apply to Sublime and more to just programming Java in general.

I wouldn't say that the solution to all Java problems is to use a Java IDE such as Eclipse or IntelliJ, but more that it helps to know what any tool (including Sublime) is doing for you behind the scenes so you can diagnose problems easier.

In the specific case of Sublime Text, the editor ships with two Java related build systems for you to use.

The first of these, `JavaC.sublime-build`, looks like this:

```json
{
    "shell_cmd": "javac \"$file\"",
    "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.java"
}
```

This just invokes `javac` on the current file with no other command line arguments. Thus, all it does is compile the current file; in simple cases that's good to verifying that your Java code is valid, but as soon as you start doing anything more complex (or wanting to actually run your code), you're going to run into problems.

The second build system that ships, `Ant.sublime-build`, looks like this:

```json
{
    "cmd": ["ant"],
    "file_regex": "^ *\\[javac\\] (.+):([0-9]+):() (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}",
    "selector": "source.java",
    "keyfiles": ["build.xml"],

    "windows":
    {
        "cmd": ["ant.bat"]
    }
}
```

This one invokes `ant`, which is a build system for Java written by Apache and a much better fit for doing anything in Java from Sublime if you're interesting in using just core Sublime without any third party packages.

To go this route you need to create a `build.xml` file that describes your project and how it should be built and run. That's far out of scope for an ***SO*** answer, but the [Ant Manual](https://ant.apache.org/manual/) includes some tutorials that may be of help.

To get you started, here's a minimal working example based on your original question.

The directory structure in this example looks like so:

```
.
|-- Chapter02
|   `-- Question1
|       `-- MyClassTryingToImport.java
|-- Helperlib
|   `-- MyClass.java
`-- build.xml
```

The contents of the files in question:

#### MyClassTryingToImport.java

```java
package Chapter02.Question1;

import Helperlib.MyClass;

public class MyClassTryingToImport
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MyClass helperClass = new MyClass();

        System.out.println("I'm the one who knocks!");
        helperClass.heisenburg ();
    }
}
```

#### MyClass.java

```java
package Helperlib;

public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass() {}

    public void heisenburg ()
    {
        System.out.println("Say my name!");
    }
}
```

#### build.xml

```xml
<project default="run">
    <target name="build_helper">
        <javac srcdir="Helperlib/" includeantruntime="false" />
    </target>

    <target name="compile" depends="build_helper">
        <javac srcdir="Chapter02/Question1/" includeantruntime="false" />
    </target>

    <target name="run" depends="compile">
        <java classname="Chapter02.Question1.MyClassTryingToImport" />
    </target>
</project>
```

The first thing to note here (which your posted example is missing) is that if you're going to have your java classes in a relative directory structure, all files need to have a package declaration that matches the folders they're in, or the java run time isn't going to be able to find the classes.

The sample `build.xml` file includes three targets; one to compiler the helper code, one to compile the class that uses the helper code, and one that actually runs the program.

The dependencies are set up so that by default ant wants to `run` your code, but to do that it needs to first `compile` it, and before it can do that it needs to `build_helper` to get the helper code built.

Assuming you have `ant` installed, and it's in the path (i.e. you can open a brand new terminal, type `ant -version` and not get an error), you should be able to press the build key and see something like this in the output panel:

```
Buildfile: /home/tmartin/OuterDirectory/build.xml

build_helper:
    [javac] Compiling 1 source file

compile:
    [javac] Compiling 1 source file

run:
     [java] I'm the one who knocks!
     [java] Say my name!

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
[Finished in 0.7s]
```

As a "proper" build system, `ant` is intelligent about building things; things won't be compiled unless their class file is missing or the source code is newer, so you don't waste time compiling things that haven't changed.

The location of the `build.xml` is important; it needs to be stored in the same folder as your `sublime-project` file if you're using one, or the first opened folder (i.e. the top one listed in the side bar) if you're not. In order to change how that works, you need to customize the build file first.

Note also that this is probably not the greatest example of an `ant` build system and that there are other tools that could also be used to do this, although Sublime doesn't directly support them out of the box and you would need to create a custom build to use them.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
1. I got a 'Could not find _____. Make sure you have it in your classpath' when I compiled with the build.xml (I have checked that its the correct path, along with spelling errors, but don't know where that error is coming from).
2. if you have more than one file that needs to import the custom packages, you simply add onto the build.xml file right ? or is there an more efficient way to accomplish this already built-in?

Comment: Does that error happen with the example code I provided above or with your own code?